# Specify runner version within github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to set the version of a github action runner?

I'd like to set the version to `v2.273.6` i.e. https://github.com/actions/runner/tree/v2.273.6 as they've deprecated the usage of `set-env`, which I'll refactor, but to get around this and allow my code to deploy in the mean time, I'd like to rollback the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot downgrade GitHub-hosted runner yourself. GitHub-hosted runners are maintained and updated automatically by GitHub. You can, however, set up your own [self-hosted runner](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) with a particular version and use it instead. Personally, I think refactoring to [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files) instead of staying with the deprecated `set-env` workflow command is much less effort than setting up a self-hosted runner.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I feared this was the case. I've refactored my code to use environment files instead of using set-env.